# Python class giving error Traceback

Tags: python, class, traceback

sorry for a stupid question maybe but I am very very new to python and created one of my first classes. But its giving error and I am kinda clueless. Here is the code

```
class Student:
    studentCount = 0
    averageGPA = 0

    def __init__(self, studentID, studentName, studentGPA):
        self.studentID = studentID
        self.studentName = studentName
        self.studentGPA = studentGPA
        Student.studentCount += 1
        Student.averageGPA += 3 

    def displayCount(self):
        print ("Total Students %d" % Student.studentCount)

    def displayStudent(self):
        print ("ID : ", self.studentID, ", Name : ", self.studentName, ", GPA : ", self.studentGPA)
    def averageGPA(self):
        print("Average GPA is : %d" % Student.averageGPA/Student.studentCount)

def main():
    student1 = Student("54466","Zara", 3)
    student2 = Student("48887","Manni", 4)
    student3 = Student("41187","Sam", 3)
    student1.displayStudent()
    student2.displayStudent()
    print ("Total Students %d" % Student.studentCount)
    print ("Student's average GPA %d" % Student.averageGPA)

main()
```

and the error it is giving is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/CS 120/lab7_2.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "Z:/CS 120/lab7_2.py", line 21, in main
    student1 = Student("54466","Zara", 3)
  File "Z:/CS 120/lab7_2.py", line 10, in __init__
    Student.averageGPA += 3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'
```

Please help me out with this problem. Again sorry if this question sounds stupid as I m very new!!!

Comment: you are passing the gpa as a string = is there a reason to do that ?

Comment: well its a number so can be passedby int also. see edited

Comment: `averageGPA` is a function, not a string, so you can't add `studentGPA` to it.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the gpa as a string : is there a reason to do that. It would be better if you did this :

```
student1 = Student("54466","Zara", 3)
```

As others have said also that AverageGPA is the name of a method, so you need another name for the class attribute.

ALso you will probably find that your average will come out wrong if you are using Python 2.7

Comment: now it says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/CS 120/lab7_2.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "Z:/CS 120/lab7_2.py", line 21, in main
    student1 = Student("54466","Zara", 3)
  File "Z:/CS 120/lab7_2.py", line 10, in __init__
    Student.averageGPA += studentGPA
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'`

Comment: okay I did some changes while and see the new edited question and error\

Comment: why studentCount keeps working there and not averageGPA... both are defined in same way